# How can get a substring from a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a large string and it’s stored in a string variable, *str*. And I want to get a substring from that in C#.

Suppose the string is: `" Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position, "`

The substring result what I want to display is: `The substring starts at a specified character position.`

Comment: Why do you want to use Substring? There are probably better ways to do what you need then using Substring with a magic number, but since you haven't told us what your main goal is, it's difficult to suggest better approaches.

Answer (score 29):

You could do this manually or using the [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) method.

Manually:

```
int index = 43;
string piece = myString.Substring(index);
```

Using IndexOf, you can see where the full stop is:

```
int index = myString.IndexOf(".") + 1;
string piece = myString.Substring(index);
```

Comment: +1 For also suggesting an approach that doesn't use magic numbers. Though really the question is unclear on what needs to be done and why.

Comment: I would suggest `int index = 1+myString.IndexOf(".");
string piece = myString.Substring(index);` to omit '.'

Answer (score 23):

```
string newString = str.Substring(0, 10);
```

will give you the first 10 characters (from position 0 to position 9).

See *[String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)*.

Comment: Taken right from the site. What if I want the 1025th character and the next 1024 chunk from there ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of getting a substring from the 14th character to the end of the string. You can modify it to fit your needs.

```
string text = "Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position.";

// Get substring where 14 is the start index
string substring = text.Substring(14);
```

Comment: adrian, sorry I don't normally do downvotes (easily) but i this case i had to. not only is this a bit 'unsafe', you also don't follow up with any logic as to why you've chosen the magic # 14 (in fact that lands us at 'string from this...'). I just don't get it. again, sorry about this but i felt i had to point this out.

Comment: 14 is just a random number, I don't feel like I should count the characters of string for Riya, he propobly can do that himself... My answer is just an example of how to get part of the string, I don't intend to give full solution to this. In my opinion for such simple problems its better to point to right direction than give full code for copy&paste...

Comment: adrian - i was basing my edginess on the fact that the question explicity asked : Substring result what i want to display is: `The substring starts at a specified character position.` therefore, i couldn't see the correlation in your answer (other than taking the substring as being a literal interpretation of the question). that said, i get your point re giving pointers, rather than full answers. all the best for now

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer so it is clear that this is only example of using substring :)

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption that you want to split on the full stop (.), then here's an approach that would capture all occurrences:

```
// Add @ to the string to allow split over multiple lines
// (for display purposes to save the scroll bar from 
// appearing on a Stack Overflow question :))
string strBig = @"Retrieves a substring from this instance.
            The substring starts at a specified character position. great";

// Split the string on the full stop, if it has a length>0
// then, trim that string to remove any undesired spaces
IEnumerable<string> subwords = strBig.Split('.')
    .Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(x => x.Trim());

// Iterate around the new 'collection' to sanity check it
foreach (var subword in subwords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(subword);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution using index in C# 8:

```
string s = " Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position, ";

string subString = s[43..^2]; // The substring starts at a specified character position
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position. Some other text";

string result = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('.') + 1,text.LastIndexOf('.')-text.IndexOf('.'))
```

This will cut the part of string which lays between the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data =" Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position.";

var result = data.Split(new[] {'.'}, 1)[0];
```

Output:

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position.

Answer (score 0):

All answers used the main string that decrease performance. You should use `Span` to have better performance:

```
var yourStringSpan = yourString.AsSpan();
int index = yourString.IndexOf(".") + 1;
string piece = yourStringSpan.slice(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if someone looking for this after all those years..
You can get your desired substring from a string by this line of code.

```
string text = "Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position, ";
text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

It's easy to rewrite this code in C#...:

[image]

This method works if your value is between two substrings!

**For example:**

```
stringContent = "[myName]Alex[myName][color]red[color][etc]etc[etc]"
```

The calls should be:

```
myNameValue = SplitStringByASubstring(stringContent, "[myName]")

colorValue = SplitStringByASubstring(stringContent, "[color]")

etcValue = SplitStringByASubstring(stringContent, "[etc]")
```

Comment: First, you should post your code as text, the image can be broken link and cannot be searched.  Second, you should use OP's sample if you think your answer is correct