# How can I keep the last 6 digits number in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, digits

If I copy " BOB3 27QK DEPM PJ7J T25G SJZI CJA5 BO5O|123456  " and I want to pass it to my text box, and get only the last 6 digits number in my text box, How to do in c#?

Comment: In this case, you could use string.split() on the "|" character. Otherwise, you could use .substring and start at .length - 6.

Comment: Can you show the codes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get substring from string in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203052/how-to-get-substring-from-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Using .Split would look like this:

```
string myString = "BOB3 27QK DEPM PJ7J T25G SJZI CJA5 BO5O|123456";
        char[] mySplitChars = { '|' };
        string[] myArray = myString.Split(mySplitChars);
        Console.WriteLine(myArray[1]);
```

Using .Substring would look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(myString.Length - 6));
```

The latter is probably preferred because it is shorter and it does not rely on the "|" character being present. The former would be preferred if the "|" is always present but the number of characters at the end can change.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing it your text box? If it's just getting the last n characters:
[refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851970/15147229)