# How to get a bit range from a hexadecimal string and convert it to an integer?

Tags: c#, string, range, hex, bit

Im asking this question, because couldn't find a solution for this particular case.

I need to extract value (as int or byte) from a hex string and from a given range of bits. For example:

hexString = "0x34840A00"

bits (from calc): 00110100 10000100 00001**010** 00000000

Now I need bits from 8 to 10: 010

Now convert to int/byte value. Any help? Im struggling with understanding of bit operations here.

Comment: Use the [Convert.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) overload which takes the base of the from object. Like so: `int result = Convert.ToInt32("0x34840A00", 16)`

Comment: I need to extract value from a bit range, not the whole hex :P

Comment: Without using a pure string sloution, you need to use bit mask and shift as exposed by @FrederikHoeft's answer (not checked) - [C# how convert large HEX string to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617284/) • [How to get substring from string in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203052/) • [Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/) • [Convert binary string into integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149728/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first use `Convert.FromHexString(hexString)` to get the bytes from your hex string. Then you could either use unsafe pointers or `BitConverter.ToInt32()` to convert said bytes to a 32 bit integer to which you can then apply bit shifts and other bit wise operations to extract the bits you need. For example:

```cs
string hexString = "0x34840A00";
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(hexString);
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
// myInt looks like this 00110100 10000100 00001010 00000000
// now shift by 8 bits to the right
myInt >>= 8;
// now it looks like this 00000000 00110100 10000100 00001010
// to get the value of the last 3 bits we need to set the first 29 bits to 0
// so we AND them together with 29 0's followed by 3 1's:
myInt &= 0x00000007;
// which results in the following bits:
// 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
// leaving you with an integer of the value 010 in binary or 2 in decimal
```

The bit shifting and AND-ing always follows the same rules:

1. If you want the bits starting at index `n` (as counted from the right-most/least significant bit) then shift right by `n` bits (in your example `n=8` (you don't care about the rightmost 8 bits)).
2. let `m` be the number of bits you want to keep starting at position `n` (in your example you want to keep 3 bits `010`). AND the result together with the integer `2^m - 1`. In your example `m=3` this would be `2^3-1 = 8-1 = 7`. Therefore we do `myInt &= 0x00000007;` or in short `myInt &= 0x7;`.

**Edit: for older .NET versions and simplifying**

```cs
string hexString = "0x34840A00";
int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16);
// myInt looks like this 00110100 10000100 00001010 00000000
// now shift by 8 bits to the right
myInt >>= 8;
// now it looks like this 00000000 00110100 10000100 00001010
// to get the value of the last 3 bits we need to set the first 29 bits to 0
// so we AND them together with 29 0's followed by 3 1's:
myInt &= 0x00000007;
// which results in the following bits:
// 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
// leaving you with an integer of the value 010 in binary or 2 in decimal
```

The reusable (and pretty fast) approach would therefore be a method like this:

```cs
private static int GetBitsFromHexString(string hexString, int startIndexFromRight, int bitsToKeep)
{
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16);
    // shift by startIndexFromRight bits to the right
    result >>= startIndexFromRight;
    // AND the bits together with 32 - bitsToKeep 0's followed by bitsToKeep 1's:
    int bitmask = (1 << bitsToKeep) - 1; // is the same as 2^bitsToKeep - 1.
    // apply bitmask
    result &= bitmask;
    return result;
}
```

Which you would call like this in your example:

```cs
int result = GetBitsFromHexString("0x34840A00", 8, 3);
// result is 2 or 010 in binary
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution and even more for comments in the code :)

Comment: One more question: my NET is older and does not have any Convert.FromHexString.

By the way, did you forget to pass one more agument into BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes) (start index) ?

Comment: @PanBocian Oh yes you're right. The start index argument would have to be `0` in the call to `BitConverter.ToInt32`.  Indeed `Convert.FromHexString()` was only introduced with .NET 5 as far as I am aware but there are lots of other questions on that here on StackOverflow :) take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) and use one of the many ways to convert a hex string to bytes :)

Comment: An easier alternative to `Convert.FromHexString` and the BitConverter trickery would be to use `Convert.ToInt32("0x34840A00", 16)` as @MindSwipe mentioned in the comments.
@PanBocian I updated the answer accordingly.